# Extjs datefield manually show picker

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to show a datefield picker manually when a certain condition is met.

```
Ext.getCmp('datef').getPicker().show();
```

This is working fine, but the problem is the alignment of the picker. It's always appearing in the center of the browser window but i would like it to appear under the datepicker.

Here is a fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mh5

How can i ensure the picker always appears aligned under the datefield when i manually show it in the code ?

Comment: Call the `expand` method.

Comment: Thanks very much, works perfect. I'll mark as the answer if you want to add it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier to invoke expand that already has all the functionality of aligning

`Ext.getCmp('datef').expand();`